# Gradle installation error : Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've installed `Android.Studio.2021.3.1.17.x64` and then i installed Sdk from [mega](https://mega.nz/file/AwNhlQrL#tvBtwcDRo9L0MCjazlH_3_1IZHkbMIy7ohS88e4DmPs) with no error but when i wanted to create a new project in java, android studio automatically started to download gradle and it returned this error:

`Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources`

also the `build.gradle` file (project level) is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
```

- i used vpn and tried gradle in offline mode but it did'nt solve the problem.

Creating a new android project, in gradle installation

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle files?

Comment: Of course, i edited my question and now it cotains the code of build.gradle file.

Comment: Since `com.android.application` is added to the project build.gradle file, it usually comes down to the following:

- the Google Maven repository is not listed in your `settings.gradle` file
-the Android Gradle plugin is not compatible with your Gradle version

Comment: versioin compatibility according to this tutorial? https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle